# How Do I Rearrange a Stacked Area Plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new to R and creating a stacked area plot with ggplot2. I have managed to get this far:

[image: my plot]

using the following code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(year,deaths,group=country, fill=burden)) +
 
geom_area() +


geom_area() +

scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "dark red")
```

The issue I am having is that I would like all the red countries to be grouped together, and the same for grey countries, like this:

[image: ideal plot without legend]

The following returns the correct plot, but without a legend:

```
ggplot(modeldf1, mapping = aes(year,deaths,group=country)) + 
geom_area(fill="light grey") +
geom_area(fill="dark red",
        data=modeldf1 %>% filter(country %in% high_burden_countries))
```

Comment: just add  fill=burden inside aes in ggplot and remove fil=="" from geom_area

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help

Comment: @yuliaUU thanks, do you mean like this:


 ggplot(wmrdf2, mapping = aes(year,deaths,group=country, fill=burden)) + 
    geom_area() +
    geom_area(data=wmrdf2 %>% filter(country %in% high_burden_countries))

Comment: almost: you need to give the actual dataset data: eg you mention `modeldf1` or `df`, or `wmrdf2` - you need to provide the actual data so we can run your code, you can do it with `dput(df)`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to arrange your data by `burden`, then convert `country` to a `factor` which the order of the levels set according to the order of the data, which could be achieved via `forecast::fct_inorder`:

Using a minimal repdroducible example based on the `gapminder::gapminder` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df <- gapminder::gapminder |> 
  rename(deaths = lifeExp) |> 
  mutate(burden = if_else(continent %in% c("Africa", "America"), "high burden countries", "low_burden_countries"))

# Order
df <- df |> 
  arrange(burden) |> 
  mutate(country = forcats::fct_inorder(country))

ggplot(df, aes(year, deaths, group = country, fill = burden)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "dark red"))
```

[image]